# ddrescue really slow on failing drive

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, ddrescue

I have a failing drive which reads at 24 kbit/s. 
As it its total capacity is 3.4 TB,
it will take probably 3 years to recover the data. 
Is there any way if performing a backup of the MFT (table of contents),
then every potential sector which reads at a better rate as an image file so I could mount in the meantime even if it will be incomplete in order to recover some "critical" files ASAP?

Comment: `ddrescue` has a command where you can skip sectors. You could try skipping forward to see if later blocks have a faster speed.

Comment: You can set it to spend less time retrying things it can't read.. or retry it less times.

Answer (score 0):

`ddrescue` has some options that can speed up at least the first pas, but this is
done manually on a trial and error basis.

The option `-a, --min-read-rate=<bytes>` specifies the minimum read rate of
good areas in bytes/s.
Specifying a size like `10M` may skip first areas that are still readable
but extremely slowly, continuing with areas that can still be read quick enough.

You could also run in `--reverse` mode to read the disk back-to-front,
or force it to start at a specific offset with `--input-position=X` to skip
into a faster region.

The options of `--no-scrape` or `--no-trim` might be able to speed up the recovery
of the easy parts by entirely omitting trying the damaged sectors.
You could also try values for the `--skip-size` option to see if larger or smaller
values than the default will speed things up.